Reconstruction of the probability of the uncut state fails
I tried to follow the example from the paper "CutQC: Using Small Quantum Computers for Large Quantum Circuit Evaluations" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02333).
Some hints were also given in the article
"https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29569/is-there-a-clear-understandable-example-of-quantum-circuit-cutting-i-can-use-to".
Unfortunately, I can't get the right result. The simulation in IBM Composer gives a probability value for |01010> of "0.00000 -0.21339i", while the reconstructed probability gives "p01010 = 0.21339 -0.21339i".

I use the following C code:
// Probabilities, using a simulator
Complex Original[32] = {{0.213388,-0.301777},{0.088388,0.000000},{-.088388,0.000000},
{0.213388,-0.125000},{0.213388,-0.125000},{-0.088388,0.000000},{0.088388,0.000000},
{0.213388,-0.301777}, {0.125000,-0.088388},{0.000000,0.213388},{0.000000,-0.213388},
{-0.301777,-0.088388},{-0.301777,-0.088388},{0.000000,-0.213388},{0.000000,0.213388},
{0.125000,-088388},{-0.088388,0.051777},{0.036612,0.000000},{-0.036612,0.000000},
{-0.088388,0.125000},{-0.088388,0.125000},{-0.036612,0.000000},{0.036612,0.000000},
{-0.088388,0.051777},{0.125000,0.036612},{0.000000,0.088388},{0.000000,-0.088388},
{-0.051777,0.036612},{-0.051777,0.036612},{0.000000,0.088388},{0.000000,0.088388}, {0.125000,0.036612}};
Complex SubCircuit1_I[8] = {{0.353553,-0.353553},{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}, {0.353553,-0.353553},{0.353553,0.000000},{0.000000,0.353553},{ 0.000000, -0.353553 },
{-0.353553,0.000000}};
Complex SubCircuit1_X[8] = {{0.500000,-0.250000},{0.000000,0.250000},{0.000000,-0.250000}, {0.000000,-0.250000},{0.000000,-0.250000},{0.000000,-0.250000},{0.000000,0.250000},
{0.500000,-0.250000}};
Complex SubCircuit1_Y[8] = {{0.500000,-0.250000},{0.000000,0.250000},{0.000000,-0.250000}, {0.000000,-0.250000},{-0.250000,0.000000},{-0.250000,0.000000},{0.250000,0.000000},
{-0.250000,-0.500000}};
Complex SubCircuit2_0[8] = {{0.603553,0.000000},{0.603553,0.000000},{0.000000,-0.250000}, {0.000000,-0.250000},{-0.250000,0.000000},{-0.250000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.103553}, {0.000000,0.103553}};
Complex SubCircuit2_1[8] = {{0.000000,-0.250000},{0.000000,0.250000},{0.603553,0.000000},
{-0.603553,0.000000},{0.000000,-0.103553},{0.000000,0.103553},{0.250000,0.000000},
{-0.250000,0.000000}};
Complex SubCircuit2_Plus[8] = {{0.426777,-0.176777},{0.426777,0.176777},{0.426777,-0.176777},
{-0.426777,-0.176777},{-0.176777,-0.073223},{-0.176777,0.073223},{0.176777,0.073223},
{-0.176777,0.073223}};
Complex SubCircuit2_i[8] = {{0.603553,0.000000},{0.250000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.250000},
{0.000000,-0.603553},{-0.103553,0.000000},{-0.250000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.250000},
{0.000000,-0.103553}};
// Reconstruction of probability of the uncut state |01010>
Complex p11, p12, p13, p14, p21,p22, p23, p24, p01010;
Complex CHelp = {2.0, 0 };
p11 = SubCircuit1_I[2] + SubCircuit1_I[3] + SubCircuit1_I[2] - SubCircuit1_I[3];
p12 = SubCircuit1_I[2] + SubCircuit1_I[3] - SubCircuit1_I[2] + SubCircuit1_I[3];
p13 = SubCircuit1_X[2] - SubCircuit1_X[3];
p14 = SubCircuit1_Y[2] - SubCircuit1_Y[3];
p21 = SubCircuit2_0[2];
p22 = SubCircuit2_1[2];
p23 = CHelp * SubCircuit2_Plus[2] - SubCircuit2_0[2] - SubCircuit2_1[2];
p24 = CHelp * SubCircuit2_i[2] - SubCircuit2_0[2] - SubCircuit2_1[2];
Serial.printf("p11 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p11.real(),  p11.imag());
Serial.printf("p12 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p12.real(),  p12.imag());
Serial.printf("p13 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p13.real(),  p13.imag());
Serial.printf("p14 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p14.real(),  p14.imag());
Serial.printf("p21 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p21.real(),  p21.imag());
Serial.printf("p22 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p22.real(),  p22.imag());
Serial.printf("p23 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p23.real(),  p23.imag());
Serial.printf("p24 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p24.real(),  p24.imag());
p01010 = (p11 * p21 + p12 * p22 + p13 * p23 + p14 * p24) / CHelp;
Serial.printf("p01010 = %.5f  %.5fi\n", p01010.real(),  p01010.imag());
Serial.printf("Original |01010> = %.5f  %.5fi\n", Original[10].real(),  Original[10].imag());
Output:
p11 = 0.00000 0.00000i
p12 = 0.70711 -0.70711i
p13 = 0.00000 0.00000i
p14 = 0.00000 0.00000i
p21 = 0.00000 -0.25000i
p22 = 0.60355 0.00000i
p23 = 0.25000 -0.10355i
p24 = -0.60355 0.75000i
p01010 = 0.21339 -0.21339i
Original |01010> = 0.00000 -0.21339i
I thank you for any hints...
